# Need an editable TextBox in C# WinForms which can show HTML Content

Tags: c#, html, winforms, textbox

I am designing a WinForm application , in which I need to show a html content (without any picture), just some content with some formatting(like color, Bold, Italic,Bullet points etc.),

I know there is WebBroswer control, but it can only show the content ,

```
webBrowser_Description.DocumentText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(testDesignStepList[0].Description);
```

It can't be used as a textbox. where you can change your text, 
also I tried something like this over text box :

```
textBox1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(testDesignStepList[0].Description);
```

also looked to some SO post , which suggest [TextEditor with html output][1],

[1]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15559/A-Windows-Forms-based-text-editor-with-HTML-output, but it says refering to a exe, which sounds little different , to have a separate, for a simple task .

Any easy workaround as per my requirement, would be helpful .

Comment: Did you try RichTextBox? Also have a look at this https://htmltorichtextbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Who told you this is a simple task? Bill?